# Need to return json data from a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to return some json data from controller. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this manually:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    return Content("this is a string literal, which can be HTML, XML, JSON, etc.");
}
```

But I think I remember an actual JSON return object before, though I've never used it.  Something like:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
  return Json(new {thing1="first thing", thing2="second thing"});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple. it's called [JsonResult](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx)